# Receiving HTTP 500 Error when saving Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, http-error-500

We are receiving an HTTP 500 error anytime we try to save a configurable product with a large number of variations. The error seems to happen anytime we create a product with over 100 variations.

After hitting save, the spinner will pop up as usual, like it is saving the product. After a few seconds the page will just crash and display the 500 error.

I assume this has to do with resources somewhere, but I've gone through and upped the memory limits, etc in both .htaccess and php.ini files and not had any luck getting it to behave differently.

Anybody have any recommendations or suggestions on getting around this issue or tracking down what is actually causing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking the server logs for php and apache/nginx to check whats going on, another way if you are on a development site is to edit the app/bootstrap.php file and uncomment this line:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This change will print errors on the browser, don't forget to revert this change when you launch your site